# Recent error "Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).ClassyLoader is not a function" on my Joomla website

Tags: jquery, joomla

My website is currently showing the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).ClassyLoader is not a function ... custom.js:4

When I go to that file, I see the following code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.loader').ClassyLoader({
    percentage: 98,
    speed: 30,
    fontSize: '50px',
    diameter: 90,
    lineColor: 'rgba(51,51,51,1)',
    remainingLineColor: 'rgba(220,220,220,0.7)',
    lineWidth: 9
  });
});
```

I'm not fluent in jQuery, so I'm not sure why it suddenly doesn't see this as a valid function. There are a couple similar errors pointing to different spots in the same file, such as this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).magnificPopup is not a function

Which goes to this code:

```
$('.without-caption').magnificPopup({
  type: 'image',
  closeOnContentClick: true,
  closeBtnInside: false,
  mainClass: 'mfp-no-margins mfp-with-zoom', // class to remove default margin from left and right side
  image: {
    verticalFit: true
  },
  zoom: {
    enabled: true,
    duration: 300 // don't foget to change the duration also in CSS
  }
});
```

I'm assuming some update is causing the issue, as this code has not been changed in a very long time. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: jQuery doesn't update itself, so something must have changed in your code. If you believe that the libraries mentioned are referenced, check you're doing so in the right order

Comment: magnificPopup and ClassyLoader  seem to be plugins and they are missing. Check whther they are included in your page via script-tags or in your bundle.

Comment: They have never been plugins, so I don't think that's it. The code above has not been changed since it worked. How would I check to make sure they are being called in the right order in Joomla?

Comment: You are welcome to post your Joomla questions at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.